# Eclipse Kepler - Cannot configure Android ADT after installing

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

After downloading and installing the 64-bit Eclipse (Kepler version), I tried to install the Android ADT plug-in according to the directions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting). When I got to the step that said

> In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select Use existing SDKs.

there was no "Welcome to Android Development" window. Instead, I got a message that said that the location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences.

The SDK doesn't appear to be installed in the Eclipse folder, so where would I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got a message that said that the location of the Android SDK has not
>   been setup in the preferences.

That means you haven't setup preference with the Android SDK location.

Set it by giving SDK Path in `Window => Preferences => Android => SDK Location`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to know where it was installed in order to be able to provide that information. As I said, it doesn't appear to have been installed in the Eclipse folder.

Comment: @RobH Android SDK and installed in Eclipse folder? Nope, you might be having some confusion or misunderstanding. You have to download Android SDK separately from developers site.

Comment: The instructions on the web site weren't very clear on that point, but after I downloaded and installed the SDK, I was good to go.